# Loading Keras Model KeyError: 'weighted_metrics'

Tags: python, keras

I get the following error when trying to load a model through Keras:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualise.py", line 82, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 251, in load_model
    training_config['weighted_metrics'])
KeyError: 'weighted_metrics'
```

I am using `model.save("Models/ResNet.model")` to save the model and `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)` to load the model.

The computer I am training this model on has **Keras 2.1.2** and the computer I am wanting to test it on (my home computer) has **Keras 2.2.4**. Is there a way to get around this error without retraining the model or downgrading my version of Keras?

Answer (score 3):

I determined the issue:

I imported the ResNet model with `from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50` and saved it by simply using model.save(). Therefore, my model was purely Keras-related. Consequently, when I tried loading it with a Tensorflow-related import (i.e. `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)`) I got the error.

The fix was simply to change the import to be purely Keras.

`model = keras.models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be easily fixed using `compile=False` as parameter.
As an example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('your_model', compile=False)
```

Actually the reason of your issue is because of a bug while Tensorflow is compiling your model after it loaded it, so try this param, I think it should fix your issue.

Comment: oh then it complains about no attribute 'loss', no attribute 'optimizer'