# Session graph empty - multiple graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a Policy Network and CNN within the same Python file. I am only training the PN and using the CNN as a feed-forward feature extractor. I am getting an issue where the Train-PC isn't "building" the imported Keras graph into the session, and thus when I try to run a feed-forward function on the CNN (`feature_vector = self.extract_feature_vector([X_img_norm])[0]`), I get the error posted below.

The only difference between the files on the Home-PC I am developing on and the Train-PC is the way I import the model which I believe may be causing this (possibly it's not recognised). I posted previously about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368717/loading-keras-model-keyerror-weighted-metrics).

Since the Train-PC is not my own, I cannot change the version of the packages. So I am looking for a solution which does not involve downgrading versions, as the issue with importing wasn't solved through that also.

Home-PC (Mac):

```
tensorflow==1.11.0
keras 2.2.4
```

Train-PC (Ubuntu):

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.10.1
keras 2.1.2
```

Code of CNN:

```
class ResNetCNN:

    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

        with self.sess.graph.as_default():
            # Load pre-trained model from file
            self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal = models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)
            # self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal = tf.keras.models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)

            self.extract_feature_vector = K.function([self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal.layers[0].input],
                                                     [self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal.layers[-4].output])

    def feed_forward(self, img):
        """Extract the feature vector of the passed image using the pre-trained CNN."""

        # Resize observable region into input volume
        X_img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

        # Normalise feature data
        X_img_norm = X_img / 255.0

        # Extract feature vector from the pre-trained CNN (1, 4096)
        feature_vector = self.extract_feature_vector([X_img_norm])[0]

        # Reshape tensor to (4096, )
        feature_vector = np.array(feature_vector).reshape(4096, )

        # Confirm that the correct output layer was used
        assert feature_vector.shape == (4096, ), "Incorrect CNN output layer: shape = {}".format(feature_vector.shape)

        return feature_vector
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_pn.py", line 856, in <module>
    s, a, r, d_r, n = rollout(epsilon, RENDER, PolicyNetwork, ResNetCNN)
  File "keras_pn.py", line 682, in rollout
    feature_vector = ResNetCNN.feed_forward(observable_region)
  File "keras_pn.py", line 87, in feed_forward
    feature_vector = self.extract_feature_vector([X_img_norm])[0]
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2357, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1025, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

Edit:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.graph = tf.Graph()

    with self.graph.as_default():
        # Load pre-trained model from file
        self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal = models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)
        # self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal = tf.keras.models.load_model(CNN_MODEL_DIR)

        self.extract_feature_vector = K.function([self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal.layers[0].input],
                                                 [self.CNN_ResNet_Pascal.layers[-4].output])

    self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
```

Comment: You need to build the graph before starting the session.

Comment: @OrDinari I built the graph prior to starting the session yet I still get the error. I have edited the __init__ function and edited the post showing it.